# How to display value from table in Textbox in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Our website is an Education site, in this on a page we have listed the expected start date for each course. Currently this date is manually captured in the page in text box, since this is required to show on all pages changing the date every time is time consuming. We have written a small function in PHP where it capture the next start date for each course. How can we pick this date from the table and show it against each course. Please advise. 
This is the link to one of our page which has dates against each course on the [Our site which contains the page with date](http://esbfedu.com/supply-chain-management-practitioner/)

Comment: Where is the PHP function you written for date?

Comment: We have written a separate php program outside wordpress which captures the date. Now the dates are stored in a table under the same database used by wordpress. How to pick those dates and show it against the course, we are using TextBox control of Betheme template to display the contents.